The Box 6 not align



        * {margin: 0;padding: 0;box-sizing: border-box;}
        h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {font-size: 18px;}
        h2, h3, h4, h5 {border-bottom: 1px dotted black;}
        main {background-color: #fff;flex: 1;box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap;}
        body {font-family: Arial, sans-serif;background-color: #fff;color: #333;margin: 0;padding: 0;}
        p {font-size: 17px;text-align: justify;}
        header {background-color: #fff;color: #000;display: flex;align-items: center;box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);}
        .container {display: flex;flex-wrap: wrap;justify-content: center;}
        .search-box {margin-left: auto;border: 1px solid #000;border-radius: 20px;}
        .search-box input[type="text"] {padding: 10px;width: 500px;border: none;border-radius: 20px;box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);outline: none;}
        .search-box input[type="text"]::placeholder {color: #999;}
        .sidebar {background-color: #fff;color: #333;width: 180px;padding: 20px;}
        .sidebar h1 {color: #000;font-size: 18px;margin-bottom: 20px;}
        .sidebar nav ul {list-style-type: none;padding: 0;}
        .sidebar nav ul li {margin-bottom: 5px;position: relative;}
        .sidebar nav ul li a {text-decoration: none;color: #555;transition: color 0.3s ease;display: flex;align-items: center;}
        .sidebar nav ul li a i {display: inline-block;width: 20px;text-align: center;}
        .sidebar nav ul li a:hover {color: #007bff;}
        .sidebar nav ul li::after {content: '';position: absolute;left: 0;bottom: -5px;width: 100%;height: 1px;background-color: #ccc;}
        .text-container {padding: 20px;}
        .ads {margin-left: auto;}
        .text-container h2 {font-size: 18px;color: #333;margin-bottom: 10px;}
        .text-container p {font-size: 16px;line-height: 1.5;color: #666;}
        .text-container a {color: #007bff;text-decoration: none;position: relative;transition: color 0.3s ease;}
        .box-container {padding: 10px; display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap; justify-content: center;}
        .box {width: 150px;height: 150px; background-color: transparent;color: #333;text-align: center;margin: 5px; border: 1px solid transparent;border-radius: 10px;display: inline-block;padding: 20px;max-width: 175px; max-height: 175px; vertical-align: top;box-sizing: border-box; }
        .box-ads {width: 350px;height: 320px; background-color: transparent;color: #333;text-align: center;margin: 5px; border: 1px solid transparent;border-radius: 10px;display: inline-block;padding: 20px;max-width: 350px; max-height: 350px; vertical-align: top;box-sizing: border-box; }
        .box h6 a {color: black;}
        .box-special {border-color: #e74c3c; position: relative;}
        .box-special .advertisement-label {position: absolute;top: -10px; /* Adjust label position */left: 10px;background-color: #000;color: #fff;padding: 5px 10px;border-radius: 3px;font-size: 12px;}
        .box-post { border-color: #000; }
        .logo {height: 76px;width: 280px;padding: 5px;}
        footer {background-color: #2c3e50;color: #fff;text-align: center;padding: 20px;clear: both;}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Responsive Web Page</title>
    <link href="https://dca-calculators.com/files/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body>
<header>
    <img src="/files/bloghints.png" alt="Logo" class="logo">
    <div class="search-box">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Search...">
    </div>
</header>

<div class="container">
    <aside class="sidebar">
        <h1><i class="fas fa-star"></i>Quick Links</h1>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-home"></i> Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-user"></i> Profile</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-cog"></i> Settings</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </aside>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.3.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<main>

      <div class="text-container">
          <h2>This text container is below heading tag 2</h2>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam et ante et mi sagittis condimentum.
              Nulla nec urna et libero <a href="#">sollicitudin porttitor</a>. Sed nec nunc quis mi congue tempor.
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam et ante et mi sagittis condimentum.
              Nulla nec urna et libero sollicitudin porttitor. Sed nec nunc quis mi congue tempor.</p>
      </div>

      <div class="box-container">

          <div class="box-ads box-special">
              <div class="advertisement-label">Advertisement</div>
              <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/virginia.webrand.com/virginia/6Of7tf0qppA/3fc0182dc30c39f4e01af5fda35a6bb6/1754/1689193338.png" width="300px" height="250px">
          </div>

          <div class="box box-post">
              <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/virginia.webrand.com/virginia/6Of7tf0qppA/3fc0182dc30c39f4e01af5fda35a6bb6/1754/1689193338.png"
                   width="80px" height="80px">
              <a href="#"><h6>Box 5</h6></a>
          </div>
          <div class="box box-post">
              <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/virginia.webrand.com/virginia/6Of7tf0qppA/3fc0182dc30c39f4e01af5fda35a6bb6/1754/1689193338.png"
                   width="80px" height="80px">
              <h6>Box 5</h6>
          </div>
          <div class="box box-post">
              <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/virginia.webrand.com/virginia/6Of7tf0qppA/3fc0182dc30c39f4e01af5fda35a6bb6/1754/1689193338.png"
                   width="80px" height="80px">
              <h6>Box 5</h6>
          </div>
          <div class="box box-post">
              <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/virginia.webrand.com/virginia/6Of7tf0qppA/3fc0182dc30c39f4e01af5fda35a6bb6/1754/1689193338.png"
                   width="80px" height="80px">
              <h6>Box 6</h6>
          </div>

      </div>

  </main>
</div>

<footer>
    <p>&copy; 2024 Your Company. All rights reserved.</p>
</footer>
</body>
</html>



Hi, As you see on the Image, Ads box and boxes 5 as intended while other 2 boxes (number 6) aren't, any clue how to make boxes number 6 fill the space below boxes number 5?
The smaller boxes will not stop on 4 boxes but i will add more boxes later since i'm using a small number box just to see the results.
The code it self not using bootstrap, but only using pure HTML and CSS, correct me if i'm wrong.

hi thanks for information, you should try to open testing URL i provided so you can see the detail.

what do you mean by no bootstrap? You added the Bootstrap CSS.

@Raptor - Actually, the CSS link was me, because the OP included the [tag:bootstrap-5] tag. I've removed it now, because I don't think the HTML has Bootstrap classes in it. I left the tag since it's not clear to me whether to remove that or fix the title. :-)

i'm not using a bootstrap sir, you added it when you moved the code to live snippet. let me try to add whole code into live snippet.

@SuwandiChen - Why did you use the [tag:bootstrap-5] tag if you're not using Bootstrap?! (I've removed it for you now.)

sorry about it, I just edited the code and put "what the problem for the site" and " what i'm intend to do with it". Thanks anyways

@Suwandi I'm not still sure to understand what's the exact issue you are talking about.. but maybe it's because the flex container holding those boxes has justify-content: center; causing its content to be centered while still wrapping on the next line. Did you try to remove that css property?

thank you for reply, take a look on the image that might explain the problem.

@SuwandiChen I was ignoring the picture.. now that you pointed out I can better understand.. you have a different size for the first box there.. and as expected the last 2 boxes are wrapping on the next line. But the first line is made of 3 boxes and its height is like the height of the biggest element. You are looking for a masonry layout instead! you cannot achieve that using a flex container alone. The code you shared is just confusing because it doesn't address the point where your first box has a different size

Only way I can think of is to use grid and media queries to do what you need. The advertisement image (inside of .box-special) creates a spacing problem when using exact widths and heights. I created a pseudo element to fill in the missing area when the height or width is scaled beyond the max image dimensions. You could also manually position the image inside of the container after scaling the image and hiding it's overflow.
FYI, there are intelligent image cropping tools that can do it dynamically.


.box-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: dense;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(125px, 1fr));
  grid-auto-rows: 150px;
  padding: 1rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
/*
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
*/
}
.box {
/*
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
*/
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #333;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  /*
  padding: 20px;
  */
  max-width: 150px;
  max-height: 150px;
  vertical-align: top;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.box-ads {
/*
  width: 350px;
  height: 320px;
*/
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #333;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  /*
  padding: 20px;
  */
  max-width: 300px;
  max-height: 300px;
  vertical-align: top;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  grid-area: 1 / 1 / 3 / 3;
}
.box h6 a {
  color: black;
}
.box-special {
  border-color: #000;
  position: relative;
}
.box-special::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  background-color: #021b33;
  margin: 1rem;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
.box-special .advertisement-label {
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px; /* Adjust label position */
  left: 10px;
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.box-special img {
  height: auto !important;
  width: auto !important;
  max-width: 300px;
  max-height: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.box-post {
  border-color: #000;
  justify-content: space-between !important;
}
.box-post, .box-special {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: start;
  padding: 1rem;
}
.box-post *{
  margin: 0 auto;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 980px) {
  .box-post, .box-special {
    max-width: 100% !important;
  }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 674px) and (max-width: 797px) {
  .box-post:last-child {
    grid-column: span 3;
    max-width: 100% !important;
  }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 424px) and (max-width: 547px) {
  .box-post:last-child {
    grid-column: span 2;
    max-width: 100% !important;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 423px) {
  .box-special {
    max-width: calc(400px - 1rem) !important;
  }
  .box-post {
    max-width: calc(200px - 1rem) !important;
  }
}
<div class="box-container">
  <div class="box-ads box-special">
    <div class="advertisement-label">Advertisement</div>
    <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/virginia.webrand.com/virginia/6Of7tf0qppA/3fc0182dc30c39f4e01af5fda35a6bb6/1754/1689193338.png" width="300px" height="250px">
  </div>
  <div class="box box-post">
    <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/virginia.webrand.com/virginia/6Of7tf0qppA/3fc0182dc30c39f4e01af5fda35a6bb6/1754/1689193338.png"
      width="80px" height="80px">
    <a href="#">
      <h6>Box 5</h6>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="box box-post">
    <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/virginia.webrand.com/virginia/6Of7tf0qppA/3fc0182dc30c39f4e01af5fda35a6bb6/1754/1689193338.png"
      width="80px" height="80px">
    <h6>Box 5</h6>
  </div>
  <div class="box box-post">
    <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/virginia.webrand.com/virginia/6Of7tf0qppA/3fc0182dc30c39f4e01af5fda35a6bb6/1754/1689193338.png"
      width="80px" height="80px">
    <h6>Box 5</h6>
  </div>
  <div class="box box-post">
    <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/virginia.webrand.com/virginia/6Of7tf0qppA/3fc0182dc30c39f4e01af5fda35a6bb6/1754/1689193338.png"
      width="80px" height="80px">
    <h6>Box 6</h6>
  </div>
</div>



